# Jquery.Validate error message on top of form with label's name

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Is it possible to display the error message above the form like this with jQuery Validation Plugin?

[image]

I'm doing something like this, but it shows how many fields are invalid. I'm new with jQuery validation and learing so I don't have any idea about this.

```
$("#addQ").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            $("#error-message").show().text("You missed " + errors + " field(s)");
        } else {
            $("#error-message").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should make some sort of attempt at doing this before asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`showErrors`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) instead of the `invalidHandler` to do something like this...

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    var messages = '';
    $.each( errorList, function( i, val ) {
        messages = messages + "<li>" + errorList[i].message + "</li>";
    });
    $("#summary").html(messages);
}
```

OR with field names:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    var messages = '';
    $.each( errorMap, function( key, value ) {
        messages = messages + "<li>" + key + ": " + value + "</li>";
    });
    $("#summary").html(messages);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hauv7y0a/

Comment: thanks buddy. But when I fill a "foo" field error message disappears while "bar" field empty. Is it possible to hide only filled fields on blur? Thanks.

Comment: @Refresh, I've pointed you in the right direction, it's now up to you to do a little work with it.