# jQuery Validate: display validation messages that contain field name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have many mandatory fields need to be validated, I'd like to display alert messages in this format: "Please fill in" + `field label`. I know I can do it manually like this:

```js
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    Forename: "required",
    Middlename: "required",
    Lastname: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    Forename: "Please fill in Forename",
    Middlename: "Please fil in Middle name",
    Lastname: "Please fill in Last name"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
  <div>
  <label for="Forename">Forename </label>
  <input type="text" id="Forename" name="Forename">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="Middlename">Middle name </label>
  <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="Middlename">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="Lastname">Last name </label>
  <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="Lastname">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

This is okay for not too many fields, but too repeated for many fields. I tried to simplify the solution like this:

```js
var labelName = $("label").text(),
    requiredFields = ["Forename", "Middlename", "Lastname"],
    messages = {},
    prefix = "Please fill in ";

$.each(requiredFields, function (_, value) {
  messages[value] = prefix + labelName;
});

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    Forename: "required",
    Middlename: "required",
    Lastname: "required"
  },
  messages: messages
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
  <div>
    <label for="Forename">Forename </label>
    <input type="text" id="Forename" name="Forename">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Middlename">Middle name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="Middlename">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Lastname">Last name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="Lastname">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

However there is a problem: the labels in the messages are not updated, they are the same, question is: how can I make it dynamically changed to be label name of each field?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to use the `for` value from the labels in your message, or is pulling from the already populated `requiredFields` okay?

Comment: @Light I'd like to use the actual text of the label, i.e. Forename for Forename field, Middle name for Middlename field, Last name for Lastname field. The array `requiredFields` is just the keys for the object `messages`.

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835406/594235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your current method...

```
// labelName is $("label").text() - Which is the concatinated string of *all* labels
$.each(requiredFields, function (_, value) {
  messages[value] = prefix + labelName;
});
```

Should be

```
// We can fetch the text from the correct field by searching the inputs with the 'for' attribute
$.each(requiredFields, function (_, value) {
  let _label = $(`label[for=${value}]`).text().trim();
  messages[value] = prefix + _label;
});
```

---

Another way to do it would be using `.reduce()`. We can create the Object by simply looping over the `requiredFields` Array

```js
var labelName = $("label").text(),
    requiredFields = ["Forename", "Middlename", "Lastname"],
    messages = {},
    prefix = "Please fill in ";

 
messages = requiredFields.reduce((acc, label) => {
  let text = $(`label[for=${label}]`).text().trim();
  acc[label] = prefix + text;
  return acc;
}, {});

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    Forename: "required",
    Middlename: "required",
    Lastname: "required"
  },
  messages: messages
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform">
  <div>
    <label for="Forename">Forename </label>
    <input type="text" id="Forename" name="Forename">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Middlename">Middle name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Middlename" name="Middlename">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Lastname">Last name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Lastname" name="Lastname">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but the strings in the `requiredFields` are just keys for the object `messages`. The actual label text is what I'd like to use, so the alert message should be "Please fill in Middle name" rather than "Please fill in Middlename".

Comment: I've fixed both my Answer, and the change you could make to your original function - Sorry about my misunderstanding